# What are the differences between Public URL and Internal URL when configuring Alternate Access Mappings in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What are the differences between Public URL and Internal URL when configuring Alternate Access Mappings in SharePoint2010?

Updated
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184}&pID=804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is probably on this page:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173(office.12).aspx